# IE9 is cloning textareas

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, textarea

I notices some strange IE9 behavior. To every existing textarea on page it creates cloned version without id but with name set to "defaultvalue-clone-*". Because of this behavior I can't apply properly tinyMCE on textarea, because I see only cloned textarea. Is this behavior can be overwritten? Or maybe some library clones me this objects.

Comment: can you create a fiddle and replicate this issue?

Comment: What are you using to generate the page? ASP? PHP? You're suspecting a library causing this and you're probably right. But what libraries are you using?

Comment: @jfrej: Django, but only in IE9 it clones objects. In other browsers everything is OK.

Comment: @wirey: it replicate every time.

Comment: @zwierzak As jfrej pointed out, this isn't IE9, this is a plugin you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way the [DefaultValue](http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/) plugin works - it clones input fields as a fallback for the `placeholder` attribute in browsers that don't fully support HTML5.

I can see the same thing happening on their [demo page](http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/).

Are you using this or similar plugin on your site?
To disable DefaultValue, either completely remove it or look for a line like this: `$(' [placeholder] ').defaultValue();` and remove it.